# How to send JSON object from R/Shiny to Cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, cytoscape.js

I am trying to use Cytoscape.js within an R/Shiny application. A separate pipeline does some computation, and creates a properly formatted JSON object for Cytoscape.js (see [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/specifying-basic-options)). I want to then use the Shiny app to read in the file, and render the network visualization. So far I have, this working example which generates an error:

#### app.r

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(rcytoscapejs)
library(DT)
library(jsonlite)

ui <- navbarPage("Shiny Protein Visualization using Cytoscape.js",
                 tabPanel("Network",
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              actionButton("imprtJSON", "JSON Test (not working)"),
                              width=3),
                            mainPanel(
                              rcytoscapejsOutput("cy", height="600px")
                            )
                          )
                 ),
                 tags$head(tags$script(src="cyjs.js"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$imprtJSON, {
    # message <- 

    # message$elements_json <- toJSON(message$elements_json)
    # message$style_json <- toJSON(message$style_json)
    # browser()
    session$sendCustomMessage("loadJSON",
                              message = list(alertMessage = "Testing sending JSON object from R to JS",
                                             elements_json = read_json("data/graph_elements0044.json")))
  })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### www/cytojs.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("loadJSON",
        function(message) {

          //var expJson = JSON.stringify(message.elements_json);
          //var styleJson = JSON.stringify(message.style_json);

          var expJson = message.elements_json;
          //var styleJson = message.style_json;

          var cy = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),
            layout: {
              name: 'preset',
              fit: true
            },
            elements: expJson,
            style: [ 
            {
             selector: 'node',
             style: {
              'background-color': '#666',
              'label': 'data(id)'
                }
            },
            {
             selector: 'edge',
             style: {
              'width': 3,
              'line-color': '#ccc',
              'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
              'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
             }
          }
         ]
          });  
        });  
    });
```

For this example, once I press the button I want the network to be rendered and appear in the app. When I run this and pull up the developer tools console in my web browser (Chrome), I get a bunch of these errors:

[image: errors]

For completeness, here's a snippet of the `graph_elements0044.json` file I'm loading:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "ac_uniprot": "Q02535", 
            "gene": "ID3", 
            "role": "whole", 
            "id": 0, 
            "parent": 0
        }, 
        "group": "nodes"
    }, 
    {
        "data": {
            "parent_ac_uniprot": "Q02535", 
            "role": "start-end", 
            "id": 1, 
            "parent": 0, 
            "label": "0"
        }, 
        "group": "nodes", 
        "position": {
            "y": 225.0, 
            "x": 742.0
        }
    }, 
    {
        "data": {
            "parent_ac_uniprot": "Q02535", 
            "role": "start-end", 
            "id": 2, 
            "parent": 0, 
            "label": "119"
        }, 
        "group": "nodes", 
        "position": {
            "y": 225.0, 
            "x": 860.0
        }
    }, 
    {
        "data": {
            "parent_ac_uniprot": "Q02535", 
            "parent": 0, 
            "color": "#CDBE70", 
            "label": "HLH", 
            "role": "domain", 
            "id": 3
        }, 
        "group": "nodes"
    }, 
    {
        "position": {
            "y": 225.0, 
            "x": 784.0
        }, 
        "data": {
            "parent_ac_uniprot": "Q02535", 
            "role": "dom_pos", 
            "id": 4, 
            "parent": 3, 
            "label": "42"
        }, 
        "group": "nodes"
    }
]
```

When I manually go in and change the JSON file to have quotes around the `id` property, it works, but this is obviously not a practical solution. I'm relatively new to JavaScript, and I've exhausted everything I can think of to get this to work. It's obviously something with the JSON formatting...maybe Shiny's `session$sendCustomeMessage()` is not encoding the objects as needed by Cytoscape.js, but I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: Did you forget to include `cyto.js`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent No, because it's an empty file. That is purpose for my question. How to code `cyto.js` so that it can take the JSON generated from the pipeline, create the network, and send it back to shiny to be visualized in the app. I'll add an edit for clarity

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Hi, please see my edits

Comment: Why do you say that the quotes around id is not practical ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to post this as a comment because I'm not sure to understand the problematic. But this is too long for a comment.

If character values of `id` are needed but you don't want to change the file, you can do (at the beginning of the R file)

```
json <- lapply(read_json("data/graph_elements0044.json"), function(x){
  x$data$id <- as.character(x$data$id) 
  return(x)
})
```

then in `server.R`:

```
session$sendCustomMessage("loadJSON",
                          message = list(alertMessage = "Testing sending JSON object from R to JS",
                                         elements_json = json))
```

Comment: Hi Stéphane. To your comment, I meant that manually adding the quotes in my input file is not a practical way to solve my problem (i.e. each time I get a new JSON from the pipeline, I'd have to do the same thing). To your answer, this seems to have worked! Must be some difference between what cytoscape.js expects for input and how `session$sendCustomMessage` coverts R lists to JavaScript objects. I will accept this answer as it is sufficient for me to move forward, although it technically does not solve my original question.

Comment: Ok @KyleWeise, I see. What about my solution ? It is not suitable ?